# Trouble with CocoaPods

Tags: cocoapods

When i type in

```
  $ pod install
```

in the terminal i get this error:

```
   [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: unterminated string meets 

 end of file. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.
```

This is my podfile:

```
 # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 # platform :ios, "8.0"
 Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
 # use_frameworks!

 target "uncle" do
 pod "SFFocusViewLayout", ">= 3.0"
 end

 target "uncleTests" do

 end
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Missing # symbol before "Uncomment this line..." line?

Comment: You should uncomment `use_frameworks!`, not the line explaining to uncomment it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your pod file to

```
 # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 # platform :ios, "8.0"
 # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
  use_frameworks!

 target "uncle" do
   pod "SFFocusViewLayout", ">= 3.0"
 end

 target "uncleTests" do

 end
```

> `#` are comments in pod file and you have commented the use Framework part

Answer (score 0):

The comment is misleading, it should be "uncomment the line below"

Do it like this:

```
 # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 # platform :ios, "8.0"
 # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
 use_frameworks!
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
 # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 # platform :ios, "8.0"
 # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
 use_frameworks!
```